# SDK Manager in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just installed Android Studio. How do I run SDK Manager in Android Studio? The Android docs say to go to [Configure->SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).

But when I do that, the SDK Manager button is grayed out:

[image: SDK Manager grayed out]

Is there something else I need to do or download?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to link the android sdk to intelliJ. Go to Project Defaults > Project Structure. Give the path to the SDK in the Android SDK location. If this is done, you will be able to run the SDK manager. If you don't have the SDK tools, download them from the developer.android.com website.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link [to developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio#Other) and download android-sdk.zip file
You can give link by going to the File--> Project Structure(Ctrl+Alt+shift+s) and you can set the path.
Then Click on the SDK Manager Icon