# Android studio SDK location error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I would like to ADT project to Android Studio project but still have some problem. See the below picture.

[image: Error message in Android Studio]

But I think I set up SDK and JDK path correctly.

[image]

[image]
Is there anything I have to check? Your answer would be appreciate.

## EDIT

I have set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and moved the SDK into `/Users/spark/Library/Android/sdk` according to the answers. But it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`. They are recommended/needed by a number of Android tools. See [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ) and the answer by the Google folks. I don't know if Gradle knows it should use those values, though. But its the standard way to set them within the tools themselves.

Comment: Try moving your `SDK` in `Users\spark`. `Android Studio` has some issues with naming directories, so character `-` in your `adt-bundle` directory might lead it to error.

Comment: @jww, Thanks for your answer but it does not work.

Comment: @Try_me34, I think I did as your answer but still the problem is same.

Comment: @Sunghun - sorry to hear it. You should file a bug report against Gradle, and inform them they should be using `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` in the absence of any overrides to them. If Gradle did the right thing, then problems like this won't exist.

Comment: @sunghun - [SDK Manager in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26940851/608639) states the SDK must also be set at *Project Defaults → Project Structure*. Also see [SDK Manager is greyed out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26874119/608639).

Comment: You need the Java Development Kit (JDK) 7